# Is my SSD dying?

Tags: macos, ssd

I walked away from my late 2012 Retina Macbook Pro for about 10 minutes, and came back to a gray screen with a flashing folder with a question mark on it. I wasn't doing anything too disk intensive at the time. Disk is a 480 GiB OWC Aura Pro installed about a year ago.

`smartctl -a disk0` gave the below output. Being that the device is not in the database (I ran `update-smart-drivedb` moments ago), I'm wondering if the data could be incorrect? Either way, the values of Raw_Read_Error_Rate, Reallocated_Sector_Ct, and Reported_Uncorrect have me a bit nervous.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     OWC Aura Pro rMBP
Serial Number:    OW13[snip]
LU WWN Device Id: [snip]
Firmware Version: 522ABBF0
User Capacity:    480,103,981,056 bytes [480 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Sep 25 11:30:13 2014 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
[snip]
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0033   095   095   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       5999623
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2317 (36 74 0)
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2874
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x000a   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       27
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x000a   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0000   038   049   000    Old_age   Offline      -       38 (Min/Max 11/49)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   038   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 11/49)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5999623
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5999623
204 Soft_ECC_Correction     0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5999623
230 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 Temperature_Celsius     0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       4067
234 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       4019
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       4019
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       3458

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Its normal for SSDs to reallocation sectors.  I would use a SSD tool to determine the health of the drive, S.M.A.R.T data alone, isn't enough.

Comment: Is there a particular tool you recommend?

Comment: Re: reallocated sectors, are you saying the threshold on that is incorrect? What about Reported_Uncorrect? I assume that's uncorrectable ECC errors?

Comment: I don't do software recommendations when a Google search results in several dozen quality programs.  My comment was to indicate that SSD reallocate sectors all the time to extend their lifespam.

Comment: "When a Google search results in several dozen quality programs" - and how many dozens of not quality programs? :-)

Comment: For what it's worth my friend had this same issue with the flashing folder with a question mark on it and it turned out to be a failing SSD.

Answer (score 1):

What does the S.M.A.R.T. status in your system's Disk Utility say? I'd like to caution against relying solely on S.M.A.R.T. as a measure of drive health.

If you have concerns about the drive, it's [an OWC product](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/SSDAP12R480/) and has a warranty ([*a particularly good warranty*](http://eshop.macsales.com/Service/warranty/owc_ssd_aura_pro.cfm)). Call them. Ensure you have backups.

Comment: Disk Utility is pretty unhelpful. S.M.A.R.T. Status: Verified.

Comment: Well, don't place too much stock in the S.M.A.R.T. output. Make sure you have a backup routine and check the values to see the rate at which they're incrementing. Or call OWC if this happens again.

Comment: I called OWC. Their tech support told me to download some "speed tools" utility. When I asked why, the guy started reading off a list of features, and went on about "it's got defrag - that could be helpful."

Comment: Isn't it bad to defrag SSDs?

Comment: @RsyaStudios Defraging an SSD will cause write operations; this can wear the drive out sooner. Defraging isn't as important on an ssd because the performance loss of fragmented files is less noticibly since the drive has fast access/read/write times. Defraging can be beneficial on an SSD, but usually not justifiable.